# How do I describe the rhythm in these songs?

Tags: rhythm, pop-music

Pop music, and especially house, seems to be enamored of this beat on top of the "4 on the floor" and the closest I can get to a description of it is "tropical" which is unsatisfactory. I'm looking for a more technical description of this rhythm.

Cheap Thrills (Sia) the electronic marimba? throughout the song (starts at 0:23) -

Where Have You Been (Rihanna), synth at 2:17 -

Shape of You (Ed Sheeran), electronic marimba throughout the song -

The best I can do is say that the subdivision of two beats is 3+3+2 sixteenth notes, but does this very common subdivision have a better name?

Or for the visually inclined, over four beats the asterisks represent accented sixteenth notes:

```
* . . * . . * . * . . * . . * .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually called the [tresillo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tresillo_(rhythm)).

There's a lot to check out in that link, from explanations of its origin to its use in various genres. But basically, the tresillo approximates a triplet without actually being a triplet. It's also an instance of a "maximally even" rhythm, which means that, given a particular level of subdivision, the three articulations are as symmetrically spread apart from each other as possible ("maximally even") without actually being completely even.

Edit: Though not a duplicate, be sure to also check out [What is this beat and why is it so popular](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10297/what-is-this-beat-and-why-is-it-so-popular/)

Comment: That does seem to be it, but there's a surprising (to me) lack of reference to its widespread modern usage in popular music on the wikipedia page.